# how to release memory on closing of WPF Page

Tags: wpf, garbage-collection

I want to release all occupied memory immediately  of a WPF page when its close like

- observable collection
- Crystal Report Viewer etc

Please guide me

Comment: you dont need to take care about releasing the memory in WPF, the .NET framework garbage collector takes care of this.

Comment: @FlorianGl  Or at least, it claims to.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to release all memory immediately?

Comment: Step away from Task Manager.  Memory management is not for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure, you could handle the close event.

```
<Window Closing="Window_Closing">
```

And then:

```
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
       //Free resources, close files, sockets, connections, etc.
       //Calling Dispose method where possible
    }
```

Hope helps!

Comment: It won't help - Dispose in general does not free managed memory. It sadly is the best you CAN do.

Comment: Small extension to the above. It will only mark it as being eligible for destruction - the Garbage Collector still needs to clean it up but thats at its own discretion.